# Qt Signal Slots class scope types

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, slot

Given two headers from an external SDK,

```
class A
{
  public:
   class B
   {
   };
  public slots:
   void onValue(B* b);
};

class C
{
  signal:
   void value(A::B* b);
};
```

The question is how i can connect signal and slots of C -> A since the data types are taken as incompatible in run time.

Comment: B is private in the scope of A, so you can't use it outside. You could do the unsafe thing and use a void pointer, then cast it to B pointer in the slot. But seeing that B is private, there is no possible way to emit from anywhere other than inside A.

Comment: @ddriver sorry it was a typo: B is public.

Comment: What's the error message? Seems to me that the types are actually compatible.

Comment: Theoretically they are. But qt only cares about the name in the signal and slot function when connecting and complains on runtime that connect is not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, code below report a runtime error reporting incompatibility between `signal` and `slot`:

```
QObject::connect( &c, SIGNAL( value( A::B* ) ), &a, SLOT( onValue( B* ) ) );
```

Error is:

> QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
>         C::value(A::B*) --> A::onValue(B*)

This is because `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` are macros and the compatibility of calls is resolved at runtime and fails this case when it should work as `A::B` and `B` are the same (most likely because it's apparently a simple text comparison).

But this is an old style connection command (pre Qt5).

With the new style connection command:

```
QObject::connect( &c, &C::value, &a, &A::onValue );
```

No error is reported at compilation time, nor at runtime and the connection will work.